# Get index from a list where the key changes, groupby

Tags: python, list, indexing, group-by

I have a list that looks like this:

```
myList = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

What I want to do is record the index where the items in the list changes value. So for my list above it would be 3, 6.

I know that using groupby like this:

```
[len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(myList)]
```

will result in:

```
[4, 3, 3]
```

but what I want is the index where a group starts/ends rather than just then number of items in the groups. I know I could start summing each sucessive group count-1 to get the index but thought there may be a cleaner way of doing so.

Thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `enumerate` to generate indexes along with the list.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
myList = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]

[next(group) for key, group in groupby(enumerate(myList), key=itemgetter(1))]
# [(0, 1), (4, 2), (7, 3)]
```

This gives pairs of `(start_index, value)` for each group.

If you really just want `[3, 6]`, you can use

```
[tuple(group)[-1][0] for key, group in 
        groupby(enumerate(myList), key=itemgetter(1))][:-1]
```

or

```
indexes = (next(group)[0] - 1 for key, group in
                groupby(enumerate(myList), key=itemgetter(1)))

next(indexes)
indexes = list(indexes)
```

Comment: This is great as it gives both the index of change and the value

Comment: If I wanted to only return the index value rather than the key what bit of code would I need to modify? or is this not possible with group by?

Comment: forgive my ignorance on the topic, your second answer does what I need, just provide the index.

Comment: @user965586 nothing to forgive; glad I could help.

Comment: This solution is cute, but way too complicated to be useful. The task in question is really simple, and should therefore entail a simple solution. Any time I use `itemgetter` I damn well better need it. Anyone looking at your code is gonna have a hard time figuring out what this line does. This is apparent in that the OP didn't even realize that your solution solved his problem at first.

Comment: @machineyearning I used `groupby` because he used it in the question and because it's nice to have the comparisons done at the C level instead of the Python level for performance (the whole point of `itertools` being in C). I don't agree it's too complicated to be useful or that `itemgetter` is something arcane -- it's used all the time for the `key` of `sorted`, `max`, etc. This will be faster than the loop version, and doesn't require the iterable have a length or be indexable like the list comprehension. That said, both of the other answers are good and I've already upvoted them both.

Comment: And as far as the OP not realizing my solution solved his problem, I believe he only saw the first version in my answer, not the second :) (There is a comment I deleted in there because it was obsolete that would make that more clear).

Answer (score 3):

```
[i for i in range(len(myList)-1) if myList[i] != myList[i+1]]
```

In Python 2, replace `range` with `xrange`.

Comment: Another alternative: `[i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(myList, myList[1:])) if a != b]`, this should be faster but downside is that it requires a copy of `myList`.

Comment: @agf: I don't mean to be rude, but your comment makes no sense. Do you think Python lists are implemented as linked lists? Quite the contrary; in fact, they are basically arrays, so list access is O(1). See http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @machineyearning You're absolutely right, I don't know what I was thinking -- I know they're not linked lists, just had a brainfail. Nothing rude about correcting someone :). +1, This is a good way -- so long as whatever you're working on has a length and is indexable (as the example in the question is).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x0 = myList[0]
... for i, x in enumerate(myList):
...     if x != x0:
...         print i - 1
...         x0 = x
3
6
```

Comment: This is a nice, simple example, but I would do `it = iter(myList)` then `x0 = next(it)` then `for i, x in enumerate(it)` and `print i` so you don't have to look at the first item in the list twice, and don't have to do the subtraction every time.